# Reajuste de uma LPU usando Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Olá,

Estou escrevendo um código em python, utilizando a biblioteca calculadora do cidadão, para reajustar os itens de uma LPU  a cadas 12 meses, a LPU vai ser inserida por um excel, a data base do reajsute também e
o resultado também deve ser escrito no excel. Já consigo fazer o reajuste mas estou com dificuldades em escrever o loop para o calculo a cada 12 meses.

```
#Reajuste de uma LPU utilizando um indice, via calculadora do cidadão

#bibliotecas
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from decimal import Decimal
from calculadora_do_cidadao import Ipca, Igpm, Inpc
import pandas as pd

# indice de reajuste
ipca = Ipca()
igpm = Igpm()
inpc = Inpc()

#carregar da LPU em formato xls

lpu = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Bruno/Downloads/teste_LPU_Greenwich.xlsx')

#carregar data de assinatura do cotrato

data_lpu= lpu.loc[14,'Greenwich']
print(data_lpu)

#carregar da de hoje

data_hj= (date.today()-timedelta(days=30))
print(data_hj)

#nova coluna

lpu['valor_reajustado',data_hj.year]='-'

#valor reajustado

for i in range(2,12):
    valor_reajuste= ipca.adjust(data_lpu, int(lpu.loc[i,'Greenwich']),data_hj)
    lpu.loc[i,('valor_reajustado',data_hj.year)] = round(valor_reajuste,3)

print(lpu)

#data_lpu_formatada= date.time(int(data_lpu[6:9]),int(data_lpu[4:5]),int(data_lpu[0:1])
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).